# Google Cloud Pub/Sub - INVALID ARGUMENT error in Push subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a topic & then tried to create a Subscription with "Push" delivery type. When I use the domain https://www.omnea.com/push/google-handler (the link doesn't exist), it works. However, when I use the url https://apidev2.omnea.org/push/google-handler, it throws INVALID_ARGUMENT error.

Both have the same certificate authority. The only difference I see here is the domain & sub-domain.

Is there any other reason due to which I receive this error?

Answer (score 34):

Got some hard time too figuring out what's happening.

You need to add your sub domain as verified domain in the API console: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification

Comment: how about for an AppEngine service that listens for push messages?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I don't understand why google doesn't provide this link rather than the terse "pubsub INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Comment: @IcanDivideBy0 you've saved my day, Thanks :)

Comment: For push, only secure web-hook url works. So, ensure your domain is ssl enabled and you are giving https:// url in the endpoint.

Comment: GCP error message was horrible, you save my day! tks