# Using a cloud function with Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a simple cloud function from a template and it got assigned a url as a trigger `https://us-central1-myapp-dev.cloudfunctions.net/naguib-testing`

Then I created a Pub/Sub Topic and tried to subscribe that url to it but I got an `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error appear on the console screen.

I went through a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43864653/830230) where the solution is to verify that I own the domain I am trying to connect to, but I don't own `cloudfunctions.net` :/

I can't understand how that's not supposed to work or what should I be doing?

Comment: I would suggest you to not post the cloud function trigger url publicly.

Comment: @noob that's ok i changed the name of the app to myapp, that's not the actual url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions can be created as HTTP functions (as you did) or as [Background functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background). The latter is automatically invoked via a message on a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic for example. I believe this is exactly what you'd need here.

However, if for some reason you do prefer to use your HTTP function as Pub/Sub push endpoint, you may be interested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047439/4926605), where the site verification is done via an HTML tag.